# Given $t_{0}\in[0,1]$, what is the radical of Banach algebra $C^{1}[0,1]/\{f:f(t_{0})=f'(t_{0})=0\}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, radicals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, banach-algebras, ring-homomorphism

Let $t_{0}\in[0,1]$ be given. Let $C^{1}[0,1]$ be the commutative Banach algebra consisting of continuously differentiable complex valued functions on $[0,1]$, endowed with the norm $$\|f\|:=\|f\|_{\infty}+\|f'\|_{\infty}.$$ I have shown that $$I(t_{0}):=\{f\in C^{1}[0,1]:f(t_{0})=f'(t_{0})=0\}$$ is an (algebra-)ideal of $C^{1}[0,1]$ and that $$A:=C^{1}[0,1]/I(t_{0})$$ is a 2-dimensional Banach algebra. How do I prove that the radical $\text{Rad}(A)$ is $1$-dimensional. Recall that $\text{Rad}(A)$ is the intersection of all maximal ideals in $A$, or equivalently, the intersection of all kernels of (unit preserving) algebra homomorphisms $h\colon A\to\mathbb{C}$.

I tried to construct all possible homomorphisms. I think (but I'm not entirely sure) that $1+I(t_{0})$ and $x+I(t_{0})$ form a basis of $A$ (where $x:t\mapsto t$), so any homomorphism $h$ is determined by the image of $x+I(t_{0})$ (since $h(1+I(t_{0}))$ is always $1$). But then I find that the radical is $\{I(t_{0})\}$, which is zero dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**s: One can show that there is only one (unit preserving) algebra homomorphism $h:A\to \mathbb C$.

There are probably multiple ways to show this.
As you suggested, $1+I(t_0)$ and $x+I(t_0)$ form indeed a basis of $A$.
One can show this by using the definition of linear independence (since you already know that $A$ is 2-dimensional this should be enough).
Then you can calculate the coefficients for $x^2+I(t_0)$ of that basis.
Note that
$$
 h(x^2+I(t_0))=h(x+I(t_0))^2
$$
has to be true because $h$ is an algebra homomorphism.
Using this information it turns out there is only one possibility for $h$.

It turns out that this $h$ is given via
$$
  h(f + I(t_0)) = f(t_0)
$$
where $f\in C^1[0,1]$ is a function.
It can then be shown that $h:A\to \mathbb C$ is well-defined (because $g(t_0)=0$ if $g\in I(t_0)$)
and an algebea homomorphism (this follows because the pointwise evaluation preserves multiplication and addition).

Finally, $\operatorname{Rad}(A)$ can be calculated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If $I:=I(t_{0})$, then I find that $x^{2}+I=2t_{0}(x+I)-t_{0}^{2}(1+I)$. So it follows that $h(x+I)$ must satisfy $h(x+I)^{2}=2t_{0}h(x+I)-t_{0}^{2}$. But this gives two solutions, namely $h(x+I)=\pm t_{0}$. And hence I find two homomorphisms.

Comment: @Jens $h(x+I)=-t_0$ is not a solution (unless $t_0=0$).

Comment: Of course. I forgot that $t_{0}\in[0,1]$. Thank you!

Comment: @Jens that is not the actual reason. You probably miscalculate. If you insert $h(x+I)=-t_0$ then you have $t_0^2 = h(x+I)^2 = 2t_0 h(x+I)-t_0^2 = -2t_0^2-t_0^2$ which is clearly false.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to prove the converse, i.e. that the assignment $h(x+I):=t_{0}$ determines a well-defined unit preserving algebra homomorphism?